# How to write bench mark tool for OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es

Let's say I wanted to write my own software for Android that would benchmark rendering performance. Something along the lines of 3Dmark basically. What sorts of factors should the different test cases measure? Would it simply be rendering a ton of verts? Running a ton of textures?

Are there any resources out there that are either books or online guides that might help with developing specific test cases that would exercise specific portions of a phone/tablet's GPU?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Besides vertex count and texture sizes, the other major variables you should cover in an OpenGL ES benchmark are the display resolution and the complexity of the shader programs.  You might also want to evaluate the compatibility of the OpenGL ES and EGL drivers, including extensions.  There is a real need for that on Android.